# How to make tags, comments, notecounts, date, permalink, and etc. visible?

Tags: tumblr

Can someone please help me? I'm having difficulties trying to make my tags, comments, notecounts, date, and permalink visible on my Tumblr layout. I have attempted to do it but it was all just confusing to me. [This is my blog](http://cristygftk.tumblr.com).

```
    {block:Posts}           
    <div class="posts">
        {block:IndexPage}
        {block:Text}<a class="text" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Text}
        {block:Photo}<a class="foto" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Photo}
        {block:Photoset}<a class="foto" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Photoset}
        {block:Quote}<a class="quote" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Quote}
        {block:Link}<a class="link" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Link}
        {block:Chat}<a class="chat" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Chat}
        {block:Audio}<a class="audio" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Audio}
        {block:Video}<a class="video" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Video}
        {block:Answer}<a class="answer" href="{Permalink}"></a>{/block:Answer}
        {/block:IndexPage}

        {block:Text}
        <div class="body">
            {block:Title}<div class="movedown"><h1>{Title}</h1></div>{/block:Title}
            <div class="textt">
                {Body}
                 {block:More}<p><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Read more}...</a></p>{/block:More}
            </div><!-- end .textt -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Text}

        {block:Photo}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <div class="photo">
                    {block:HighRes}<a class="highquality" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" target="_blank">{lang:High-res photo}</a>{/block:HighRes}
                    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{block:IndexPage}{PhotoURL-250}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:PermalinkPage}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}
                </div><!-- end .photo -->
                {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Photo}

        {block:Photoset}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <div class="photosett">{Photoset-500}</div>
                {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Photoset}

        {block:Quote}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <h1>"{Quote}"</h1>
                {block:Source}<div class="textt"><p>&mdash; {Source}</p></div>{/block:Source}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Quote}

        {block:Link}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <h1 class="linkk"><a href="{URL}">{Name}</a></h1>
                {block:Description}<div class="linktextt">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Link}

        {block:Chat}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                {block:Title}<h1 class="chatheader">{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}
                {block:Lines}<div class="{Alt}">{block:Label}<b>{Label}</b>{/block:Label} {Line}</div>{/block:Lines}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Chat}

        {block:Audio}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <ul class="music">
                <li><a href="{Permalink}"></a>{block:AlbumArt}<img src="{AlbumArtURL}" alt="" />{/block:AlbumArt}</li>

                {block:IndexPage}
                <div class="player">
                    <div class="audioplayer">{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>
                </div><!-- end .player -->
                {/block:IndexPage}
                </ul>

                {block:PermalinkPage}
                <div class="audiocaption">
                    <div class="audioplayer2">{AudioPlayerWhite}</div>

                    {block:Artist}<h1 class="audiopost"><span>{block:English}Artist{/block:English}{block:German}Künstler{/block:German}{block:French}Artiste{/block:French}{block:Italian}Artista{/block:Italian}:</span> {Artist}</h1>{/block:Artist}
                    {block:TrackName}<h1 class="audiopost"><span class="audioodd">{block:English}Song{/block:English}{block:German}Lied{/block:German}{block:French}Chanson{/block:French}{block:Italian}Canzone{/block:Italian}:</span> {TrackName}</h1>{/block:TrackName}
                    {block:Album}<h1 class="audiopost"><span>Album:</span> {Album}</h1>{/block:Album}
                    <h1 class="audiopost"><span class="audioodd">{lang:Plays}:</span> {FormattedPlayCount}</h1>
                </div><!-- end .audiocaption -->

                <div class="clear"></div>

                {block:Caption}<div class="audiopostcaption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
                {/block:PermalinkPage}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Audio}

        {block:Video}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <div class="videopost">{Video-500}</div>
                {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Video}

        {block:Answer}
        <div class="body">
            <div class="movedown">
                <h1 class="question">@<span>{Asker}</span> "{Question}"</h1>
                <div class="textt">{Answer}</div>
            </div><!-- end .movedown -->
        </div><!-- end .body -->
        {/block:Answer}

        {block:Date}
        <center>{block:IndexPage}<div class="indexpoles"></div>{block:IndexPage}
        {block:PermalinkPage}<div id="permapole"></div>{/block:PermalinkPage}</center>

        <div class="body2">
            <ul>
            <li class="time">{block:IndexPage}{TimeAgo}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{MonthNumberWithZero}.{DayOfMonthWithZero}.{ShortYear}{/block:PermalinkPage}</li>
            {block:PermalinkPage}{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<li class="tags"><a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a></li>{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:PermalinkPage}
            {block:NoteCount}<li class="notes">{NoteCount}</li>{/block:NoteCount}
            {block:PermalinkPage}{block:RebloggedFrom}<li class="reblog"><a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentName}</a></li>{/block:RebloggedFrom}{/block:PermalinkPage}
            {block:ExternalAudio}<li class="download"><a href="{ExternalAudioURL}" title="Download the audio.">{lang:Download}</a></li>{/block:ExternalAudio}
            </ul>
        </div><!-- end .body2 -->
        {/block:Date}
    </div><!-- end .posts-->
    {/block:Posts}

    {block:PostNotes}
    {PostNotes}
    {/block:PostNotes}

    {block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:Posts}
    {block:Date}
    {block:IfDisqusShortname}
    <div class="posts">
        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [page explaining how Blocks and variable works](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes)?

For starters, your permalink (`<a class="text" href="{Permalink}"></a>`), although it will be coded in the page, will not be visible *unless the link has text in it*.

Also there is some weird stuff going on with

```
{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Posts}
{block:Date}
{block:IfDisqusShortname}
```

Which are not closed and form a pretty complicated, not so useful hierarchy: you do not need a Date block here, and the Posts block is used to tell where the posts are generated in your layout!

Can you try to trim it down to SPECIFIC parts of the layout that are not doing what you want them to? As is it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do, because you probably are posting too big a chunk (and absent color-coding, it's not very legible).